# How to perform correct query RQ to GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I am trying to send correct query on the https://api.sorare.com/sports/graphql/playground

Anyone maybe has an experience or knows how to read this mentioned doc?

Here is the example of what I am trying to retrieve, without success:

```
query GetNbaLeaderboard($slug: String!) {
  nbaLeaderboard(slug: $slug) {
    slug
  }
}
```

Keep getting:

```
ClientError: must be defined: {"response":{"errors":[{"message":"must be defined","path":["variable","slug"],"extensions":{"code":"GRAPHQL_VALIDATIO
N_FAILED"}}],"data":null,"status":422,"headers":{}},"request":{"query":"\nquery GetNbaLeaderboard($slug: String!) {\n    nbaLeaderboard(slug: $slug)
 {\n      slug\n    }\n}\n","variables":{"slugs":["nba-gameweek-27-common-champion"]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so query is good but it also needs to have slug sent as a variable.